# How to trigger Ajax Request for filling a Form out and wait until DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, phantomjs

I am going to fill out a [Form](http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register) using JQuery through PhantomJS.

I have following script for doing that:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register', function() {
    fillTheForm();
    phantom.exit();
});

function fillTheForm () {

    page.evaluate(function() {

        var selectTags = new Array();
        selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        $(selectTags[0]).val("38");
        $(selectTags[0]).trigger('change');
    
        $(selectTags[1]).val('610');
    });         
    page.render('form.png');
};
```

after running this script, I got following message inside the console!

> Alert, JavaScript error

Also, the picture that I have, after trying to fill the Form out, tells me that the existing values for the second Select box have not changed yet and then PhantomJS could not assign the value to the second field.

Can someone please help me to solve this problem? How can I fill out this two fields using JQuery and PhantomJS?

Comment: I visited the URL, and I changed the value of the first select to "Canada" as your value "38" corresponds to. It took about 3 or 4 seconds for the state select box to load. I think that your error is occurring because your jQuery code is trying to set the field value way before it finishes loading.

Comment: How to wait after changing the first value? I am going to fill all existing fields and then click on submit button. Then I cannot put the ($(selectTags[1]).val('610')) command inside the 'window.setTimeout'. do you have any suggestion here?

Comment: Also, I just tested 'window.setTimeout' here and I got the same error!

Comment: You might need to put your `phantom.exit()` inside the timeout. So create a timeout to wait for the second `val()` call then perform the `exit()` inside the timeout.

Comment: I cannot kill Phantom inside the page.evaluate(). But, I just found that the error comes up before the second assignment! it seems that there is a problem before '$(selectTags[1]).val('610')' line! any suggestion?

Comment: The reason I'm posting these suggestions in the comments is because I am not familiar with phantomjs. So I cannot help you too much more... sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the chained selects problem. The second one is dependent on the first one and is populated via AJAX. This means that it is asynchronous. You have to wait before you can set the second value. In PhantomJS this is also problematic, because you have two contexts (page context and phantom context) that have do be "synchronized".

For example you can use

```
function fillTheForm () {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        $(selectTags[0]).val("38");
        $(selectTags[0]).trigger('change');
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.evaluate(function() {
            var selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
            $(selectTags[1]).val('610');
        });
        page.render('form.png');
        phantom.exit(); // this has to be inside, because everything is asynchronous now
    }, 3000); // assuming 3 seconds are enough time for the request
};
```

A better and more robust way would be to use [`waitFor` from the examples](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js), because it is finished as soon as the data is available. Here I have some indicators when the second select is reloaded:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register', function() {
    fillTheForm(function(){
        page.render('form.png');
        phantom.exit();
    });
});

function fillTheForm(done) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

        // custom indicators, perhaps something more elaborate is needed for general selects
        // in this case it is ok
        window._chainedSelectChildrenLength = selectTags[1].children.length;
        window._chainedSelectFirstChildText = selectTags[1].children[0].innerText;

        $(selectTags[0]).val("38");
        $(selectTags[0]).trigger('change');
    });
    waitFor(function testFx(){
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            var selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
            // use indicators
            return window._chainedSelectChildrenLength !== selectTags[1].children.length ||
                window._chainedSelectFirstChildText !== selectTags[1].children[0].innerText;
        });
    }, function onReady(){
        page.evaluate(function(){
            // continue
            var selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
            $(selectTags[1]).val('610');
        });
        done();
    }, 5000); // 3 seconds is the default
};

function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};
```

Comment: Just a question! How those two first lines will help if there is a chain of Selects? I don't get that part! Is there any way by which I can check if existing 'Select' tags will trigger an Ajax call or not? I mean before assigning value to the each of them?

Comment: Before writing your script, you open the developer tools in the browser and go to the network tab. Then you do some actions and observe the network tab. In this case I didn't even do that, because it is more likely that the zones are loaded asynchronously than having all the zones loaded for all countries at the beginning of the page load. It is much easier to program for known actions than try to catch unknown actions. To make it even more robust, you can use [page.onResourceReceived](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html)

Comment: Thanks for your helps @Artjom B. I finally solved my problem using your suggestion.